# trying to create a MFC dialog based application to read a video

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

I'm writing a program using MFC Dialog based application to read a video. I'm using videolabs package as a reference. The error which I get when I compile the program is

1>c:\users\prashanth\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\videodemo34\videodemo34\videodemo34dlg.cpp(105) : error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [36]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Can anyone say how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you post the code which is throwing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't some C errors wonderful? Good luck in learning C++. Basically the type of item on the right side of the assignment is a mismatch to the one of the left side. Without a code sample it's tough to say more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you double click on the Error message in the Visual Studio Error window and look at the code or at least post the code up here.

I would hazard a guess that you have either defined a 36 element char array or have a const string which you are then trying to copy to an item type which isn't suitable.

If you are trying to copy a filename/string then use strcpy_s. If this isn't then the code would really help!